# sending data of two fragments to firebase (Fragment wise or in one go)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments in one activity. In the first fragment, I have fields like name, email, gender and phone number and by the next button replace with second fragment and on the second fragment, I have a password and confirm password fields. Now I want to send data to firebase fragment-wise or send data of two fragments at one time(by pressing the register button which is on the second fragment).but did not know how to do that

//First Fragment

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    tools:context=".CustomerRegisterFragment">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCustomerDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
        android:text="@string/personal_details"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.28"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.439"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_name"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserName"
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_email"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserEmail"
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout1"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserPhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="Phone #:"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextUserPhone"
            android:layout_width="282dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewUserGender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_gender"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/male"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/black"
            android:checked="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_gender_male"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/female"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/black"
            android:checked="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_gender_female"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/other"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:buttonTint="@color/black"
            android:checked="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:text="@string/user_gender_other"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRegisterCustomer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="@string/btn_next"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

//Second Fragment

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    tools:context=".CustomerRegisterFragment1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.18"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewCustomerPassTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
        android:text="@string/c_password"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.28"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/CustomerRegisterFragment1.linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="288dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textViewCustomerPassTitle"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextCustomerPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#695547"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:hint="@string/customer_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#A88973" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextCustomerConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#695547"
            android:fontFamily="@font/courbd"
            android:hint="@string/cconfirm_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#A88973" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRegisterCustomer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="123dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_style"
        android:text="@string/btn_register_client"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/CustomerRegisterFragment1.linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.229" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **350** lines of layout design code for this issue and **no** Java code. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: I did not write java code yet.if I have then I will not save it from others.I paste XML just for understanding @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use bundle in fragment to pass data from one fragment to another

**Without Arch. Component...**

send data to another fragment

```
Fragment fragment = new ProductdetailFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_main,fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();                

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("product_id","value");
 bundle.putString("product_name","value");
 bundle.putString("price","value");
 bundle.putString("product_desc","value");
 bundle.putString("product_image",productmodels.get(position).getProduct_image());

 fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

get data from the previous fragment. for getting data, you have to use **key** of apply of the previous fragment.do not mismatch key argument

```
 Bundle bundle = getArguments();

 String product_id =  bundle.getString("product_id");
 String name =  bundle.getString("product_name");
 String price = bundle.getString("price");
 String description = bundle.getString("product_desc");
 String imageurl = bundle.getString("product_image");
```

**Second Way if You use Navigation Arch. Component**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("amount", amount);
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Interface;
   interface:

```
public interface FragmentInterface {
    String getName();
    String getEmail();
    String getPassword();
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class FragmentA extend Fragment implements FragmentInterface{}
public class FragmentB extend Fragment implements FragmentInterface{}
```

xxxActivity:

```
FragmentInterface fia = (FragmentInterface)FragmentA;
FragmentInterface fib = (FragmentInterface)FragmentB;
```

get Field:

```
String name = fia.getName();
String pw = fib.getPassword();
```

3. BroadcastReceiver
4. Global singleton